# Asp.net beginner issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I'm attempting to write a practice asp.net website for a bike store network.  If you look at my index view for my store object, As well as my mock db and controller, you can see that I intend for the view to print out the number and the names of the stores:

**BikeStoreEntities.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using BikeStore.Models;

namespace BikeStore.Models
{
    public class BikeStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Inventory> StoreInventory { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BikeStore.Models;


namespace BikeStore.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        BikeStoreEntities storeDB = new BikeStoreEntities();
        // GET: Store
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var stores = storeDB.Stores.ToList();
            return View(stores);  
        }
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var bike = new Inventory {SerialNumber=id };
            return View(bike);
        }
        public ActionResult Browse(string name)
        {
            var store = new Store { Name = name };
            return View(store);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using BikeStore.Models;
using BikeStore.Models;

namespace BikeStore.Models
{
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BikeStoreEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BikeStoreEntities context)
        {
            var stores = new List<Store>
            {
                new Store { Name = "Rocky Road" , City= " ", Address= " ", Phone= " ", Employees = new List<Employee>(), StoreInventory= new List<Inventory>()},
                new Store { Name = "Jazzy Drive" ,City= " ", Address= " ", Phone= " ", Employees = null, StoreInventory= null},
                new Store { Name = "Metal Foundry" ,City= " ", Address= " ", Phone= " ", Employees = null, StoreInventory= null}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
 @model IEnumerable<BikeStore.Models.Store>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Store";
}
<h3>Browse Stores</h3>
<p>
    Select from @Model.Count() Stores:
</p>
<ul>
    @foreach (var store in Model)
    {
        <li>@store.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

However, It prints out "Select from 0 Stores" and then no stores after it.  Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?  I would be happy to provide any other project files that you feel are relevant.

Comment: you aren't showing your controller.

Comment: @DanielA.White There you go.

Comment: You must have some record in your database.

Comment: From the controller code, it looks like a problem with your `BikeStoreEntities` instance.  Are you sure that your mock DB is getting properly seeded?

Comment: @Lali What do you mean?  Is this not a record?

Comment: Did you check in db after seeding?

Comment: @Lali how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't populating the entities, your local variable goes out of scope and no data is added.

```
namespace BikeStore.Models
{
    public class SampleData :    DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BikeStoreEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BikeStoreEntities context)
        {
            var stores = new List<Store>
            {
                new Store { Name = "Rocky Road" , City= " ", Address= " ", Phone= " ", Employees = new List<Employee>(), StoreInventory= new List<Inventory>()},
                new Store { Name = "Jazzy Drive" ,City= " ", Address= " ", Phone= " ", Employees = null, StoreInventory= null},
                new Store { Name = "Metal Foundry" ,City= " ", Address= " ", Phone= " ", Employees = null, StoreInventory= null}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

See the example from here on how to seed: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3

```
protected override void Seed(BookService.Models.BookServiceContext context)
{
    context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
    new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Jane Austen" },
    new Author() { Id = 2, Name = "Charles Dickens" },
    new Author() { Id = 3, Name = "Miguel de Cervantes" }
    );

    context.Books.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
    new Book() { Id = 1, Title = "Pride and Prejudice", Year = 1813, AuthorId = 1, 
        Price = 9.99M, Genre = "Comedy of manners" },
    new Book() { Id = 2, Title = "Northanger Abbey", Year = 1817, AuthorId = 1, 
        Price = 12.95M, Genre = "Gothic parody" },
    new Book() { Id = 3, Title = "David Copperfield", Year = 1850, AuthorId = 2, 
        Price = 15, Genre = "Bildungsroman" },
    new Book() { Id = 4, Title = "Don Quixote", Year = 1617, AuthorId = 3, 
        Price = 8.95M, Genre = "Picaresque" }
    );
}
```

Comment: @Huber my db is fake, man.  Its in my models folder.  I'd like to keep it that way for now.

Comment: @JamesFalter you need to populate your entities with something in order to get a value other than zero. The place where you attempt to populate your entities does nothing, it creates a list of stores which is immediately destroyed by the garbage collector (the JIT may ignore it all together). In order to get a value other than zero in your view, you need to put some actual data in the BikeStoreEntities instance your controller uses. You can populate it in the seed or using some other method like in the constructor of the controller.